# Why can't I upvote posts when my account is new?

Tags: discussion, support, voting, new-users

To upvote answers or questions I have to have 15 points. To get these I have to first create questions.
I don't understand the reasoning behind this.
Does creating questions make my upvotes more reliable or give them better quality?

Comment: It means that you've been around for a while. It prevents people from simply creating a new account and go wild with other people's reputation. Also, this probably belongs on meta.

Comment: You don't need to ask a question, you could also post an answer that gets upvoted.

Comment: The main reason is probably a way to prevent people from making lots of dummy accounts to upvote themselves. [Why are 15 reputation points required to upvote?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/41347)

Comment: Note that this restriction is only if you are really new to one Stack Exchange Community. Once you have over 200 reputation and you join a new SE community you will get the Association Bonus which catapults you past these restrictions.

Comment: also note that you are asking on the tex site, but the moderators here have no control over this, it is a network wide rule for the entire stackexchange network so to get a change you would have to ask on meta.stackexchange not tex.meta.stackexchange

Comment: I can also confirm that it's possible to get more than 15 rep without asking any questions.

Answer (score 4):

The intent here is to avoid gaming of the system through [sock puppets](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/40353/168244#:%7E:text=See%3A%20Stack%20Overflow-,Sock%20Puppet,-%5BAccount%5D) - accounts set up by a user with the intent on using them to cast illegal votes, either on their own posts, or on others.

The 15 reputation threshold is very small, and can be achieved through minimal contribution on the site. See [this list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7237/168244) of how one can gain reputation on a site:

- One of your posts is upvoted: **+10**
- One of your answers is *accepted* by the author: **+15**
- You *accept* an answer, not written by you, to a question of yours: **+2**
- A [suggested edit of yours is approved](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/76251/168244): **+2** (up to a total of +1000 per user)
- One of your answers is awarded a bounty by the user offering the bounty: **+ full bounty amount**
- One of your answers is awarded a bounty automatically: **50% or 100% of the bounty amount** (see [bounty FAQ](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/16067/5764) for details)
- You *associate accounts* of two or more Stack Exchange network sites, and at least one of those accounts has 200 or more reputation: **+100** on each site (awarded only once per site) (this reputation bonus does *not* count toward the required 10 reputation to answer protected questions)

Reference: [Why are 15 reputation points required to upvote?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/41347/168244)

Comment: I think you even get points for completing your profile.

Comment: @gernot: You used to get *badges* for doing profile-like stuff. For example, [Analytical](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/badges/109/analytical) (Visited every section of the FAQ; which is now retired) and [Informed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/badges/252/informed) (for read the entire [tour](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tour) page).